# Will someone explain me this LINQ Query in Detail, which I have applied on SharePoint Project ? Why P object is used?

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint-2013

I wanted to know what does P do in the query, I know it is an object if it is an object where it should be declared ? The Second thing I want to know is what is .cast SPListItem is doing in the query and why we need it ?

```
var dt = (from p in items.Cast<SPListItem>()
                          where (p["WorkflowName"] != null)
                             && (Convert.ToString(p["WorkflowName"]).Split(',')[1].Trim() == "Approved")
                          select new
```

Actually I am new to LINQ and want to have my concepts crystal clear.

Comment: `p` here is simply a temporary variable in the query statement, and it will be assigned one item at a time from the collection `items.Cast<SPListItem>()`. The purpose of the cast is that presumably the `items` collection is of a simpler type, such as `IEnumerable<object>`, and the `Cast` makes sure we treat them as the objects we know they are, which gives us access to properties on the objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LINQ is *conceptually* similar to a `foreach` loop; the `p` here is just a token that represents the "for each item `p` in `items`, which we will assume is a `SPListList`, apply some filter test (`where`) on the properties of the item `p`, and for those that match, apply some projection (`select ...`)".

You could *also* think of it as:

```cs
foreach(SPListItem p in items)
{
    if (p["WorkflowName"] != null && ... )
    {
        var projection = new ...
        // add/etc
    }
}
```

There is an important difference, however, in that LINQ is usually a deferred query that can, if necessary, be inspected and re-written by code that needs to - for example, to turn C# into SQL to execute against a database.

Comment: Simple Explanation which helps me out, please will you let me know what is the purpose of  .CAST ? @MarcGravell

Comment: @IbrahimInam that suggests that `items` doesn't know that it is a sequence of `SPListItem`. That could be because it is a `List<object>`, or an `IEnumerable<SomeBaseType>`, etc. The `.Cast<T>` here says "assume that each item of the sequence is a `T`" - essentially the same as the `foreach(SPListItem p in items)` does (note that this is different to `foreach(var p in items)`, which takes each `p` **as it is defined in items**, with no cast)